# How to access a structure variable inside another structure?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, member-variables

I have two `typedef struct` in header file.

```
typedef struct {
    int fallLevel;
    unsigned long lastStepTime; 
} PlayerFallStruct;

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char* name;
    int x;
    int y;
    PlayerFallStruct playerFall;

} Client;
```

I don't know how to access to `PlayerFallStruct playerFall`. If I use 
     ((PlayerFallStruct*) packetClient->playerFall)->fallLevel = 0;

compiler throws error:

> Client.c:46:4: error: cannot convert to a pointer type
>       ((PlayerFallStruct*) packetClient->playerFall)->fallLevel = 0;

Why? Where is a problem? How can I access to my `stuct`?

Comment: Try this: `(packetClient->playerFall).fallLevel = 0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy !!!! Just remember the rule for accessing the structure

```
'.' for static object of structure
'->' for pointer type obj of structure.
```

So, lets take example of your case .

Struct Client *packet_client;

**So, in your case '->' is used. And you have created static object of playerFallStruct. So, '.' operator is used to access the members inside the PlayerFallStruct.**

```
packet_client->PlayerFall.fallLevel = 0
```

Hope That Helps :) :) Happy Coding :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `Client` type variable (here, `packetClient`), the `playerFall` member variable is not a pointer. You can try accessing that with normal member reference operator, `dot` (`.`).

Something like

```
 (packetClient->playerFall).fallLevel = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you should be able to access `PlayerFallStruct playerFall` like this:

```
struct Client packetClient, *packetClientPtr = &packetClient;
//Fill client...
(packetClient->playerFall).playerFall = 0;
```

Note that this is because you're not including a pointer to `PlayerFallStruct playerFall` in your `Client` structure - you're actually declaring an entire structure.  Your syntax would work if you defined `struct Client` with a pointer to a `PlayerFallStruct`:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char* name;
    int x;
    int y;
    PlayerFallStruct *playerFall; //Note - this is a pointer!

} Client;
```

This would also necessitate creating a `PlayerFallStruct` outside of this struct (generally, I think this is the preferred means of placing structs in structs, but it's all semantics at the end of the day):

```
PlayerFallStruct playerStruct, *playerStructPtr = &playerStruct;
packetClient->playerFallStruct = playerStructPtr;
```